# STLPort, Intel compilers, build errors (though app runs fine!)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, intel, icc, stlport

Compiling my project against STLPort I get some weird build errors.  Weird, because the project runs just fine (and 20-30% faster) though you'd think the build errors would be fatal.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong and how to shut these up?

```
Linking... (Intel C++ Environment)
ipo: error #11017: Cannot open stlport_static.lib
ipo: error #11017: Cannot open libiomp5md
ipo: error #11017: Cannot open libmmt
ipo: error #11017: Cannot open libirc
ipo: error #11017: Cannot open svml_disp
ipo: error #11017: Cannot open libdecimal
ipo: warning #11020: unresolved ?_M_use_facet@locale@stlp_std@@QBEPAVfacet@12@ABVid@12@@Z
        Referenced in ipo_19005obj.obj

[and lots of other unresolved symbols from that last .obj file]
```

(libiomp5md is from Intel's openmp support, I was using that before switching to stlport, and am still running with openmp now so don't see why that should have changed).

My runtime library (in C++ Code Generation settings) is set to multi-threaded.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** it seems ipo is inter procedural optimization complaining that it can't open libraries which weren't compiled in the current build.  So understandable that these errors aren't fatal, and my output still gets built. Still, any advice appreciated.

Comment: How does something run that could not be created? Are you sure you're not running a _previous_ version of your executable?

Comment: Yup, sure (deleted everything).  Found out some more though, see edit above.

Comment: So what do you want to know, if you already found out the answer?

Comment: While I have disabled it for now to silence the linker, I wonder if there's still a way to get ipo to work?  It might make the runtime faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPO is inter procedural optimization complaining that it can't open libraries which weren't compiled in the current build.   These errors aren't fatal; the output still gets built but IPO obviously doesn't optimize the libraries it can't optimize.